# Is `versioneer` compatible with `PyPI` packaging?

Tags: python, pypi

I've been using [versioneer](https://github.com/warner/python-versioneer) for version control of [my package](https://github.com/roxyboy/xomega) and I'm currently trying to upload it to PyPI. I am getting the following error, however, when running

```
python -m twine upload --repository-url https://test.pypi.org/legacy/ dist/*

Uploading distributions to https://test.pypi.org/legacy/
Uploading xomega-0.0.1+25.g7c6a208.dirty-py3-none-any.whl
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 11.5k/11.5k [00:00<00:00, 22.5kB/s]
NOTE: Try --verbose to see response content.
HTTPError: 400 Client Error: '0.0.1+25.g7c6a208.dirty' is an invalid value for Version. Error: Can't use PEP 440 local versions. See https://packaging.python.org/specifications/core-metadata for url: https://test.pypi.org/legacy/
```

Is the version number automatically assigned by `versioneer` not compatible with `PyPI` or am I missing something elementary here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version `0.0.1+25.g7c6a208.dirty` is not a valid version number for PyPI. It indicates that your distribution was made at a point when your repository was 25 commits after the `0.0.1` tag , had a unique revision id of `g7c6a208` and was "dirty" (it has uncommitted changes).

You need to commit your changes and make a `0.0.2` tag to get a valid version number before you can upload to PyPI.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Is it somehow possible to still upload to TestPyPi? It seems to have the same restriction. But I only want to tag my commit, after making sure the resulting package can be published on PyPi.

Comment: Nope, sorry. TestPyPI is the same.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the "pep440-pre" style for versioneer instead of "pep440" in `setup.cfg`. That should produce something like `0.0.1.post0.dev25` for you which is valid to use in the upload to pypi.